# PHP multi- dimentional array merge

Tags: php, arrays

i have a multi-dimentional array:

```
$array['hello'][0][0]='a';
$array['hello'][0][1]='b';
$array['hello'][0][2]='c';
$array['hello'][0][3]='d';
$array['hello'][1][0]='e';
$array['hello'][1][1]='f';
$array['hello'][1][2]='g';
 .... // and so on
```

i want to merge them all and want it as

```
$hello[1] = 'a';
$hello[2] = 'b';
$hello[3] = 'c';
$hello[4] = 'd';
$hello[5] = 'e';
$hello[6] = 'f';
$hello[7] = 'g';
 .... // and so on
```

now i have been using `array_merge` :

```
 $hello = array_merge($array['hello'][0],$array['hello'][1]);
```

But in this i have to be specific regarding the keys ie. `0`,`1` . what if keys are not known.

**Is there any other way to do it ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work without the keys:

```
$hello = array();
foreach ($array['hello'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $hello[$k] = $v;
        }    
}
```